# Calling AWS API - Signature, Authentication Header in Swift

Tags: swift, authentication, aws-api-gateway, alamofire

I want to access a secured AWS API in alamofire, I have the access key and secret key
but I'm having issues in accessing the API. In Android we do it this way https://github.com/Ghedeon/AwsInterceptor

```
       func secure(secureAPI: securedApi, completionHandler: @escaping (Bool, String) -> ()){
        let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
        .contentType("application/json")
        ]
        
    AF.request(secure as! URLConvertible, method: .post, parameters: secureAPI, encoder: JSONParameterEncoder.default, headers: headers).responseJSON{
            response in debugPrint(response)
            switch response.result{
            case.success(let data):
                


                    if response.response?.statusCode == 200{
                        
                      print("Success")
                       
                        

                    }else{
                        completionHandler(false, "Please try again")
                    }
                

            case.failure(let err):
                print(err.localizedDescription)
                completionHandler(false, "Please try again")
            }
        }
    }
```

**Issue**

Creating Signature using access key and secret key, and attaching it with API

Comment: And what's your exact issue? Parsing?

Comment: Creating Signature using access key and secret key, and attaching it with API

Comment: @P176061HaiderTamsil did you find any solution of it?